Add a hyphen after second character and also delete on backspace
I have an input field. I need the input to have the following format: AC-123456789
When I input the characters in the field, after the second character I want the system to add the hyphen automatically just once. The first group of characters has to be a specific letter for the first character and any letter or number for the second character. The second group can only be numbers. If I want to delete using backspace, I should be able to delete also the hyphen.
So far I have:
const transformInput = (input) => {
  const inputLength = input.replace('-', '').length;
  if (inputLength > 1 &&  input[2] !== '-') input = `${input.slice(0,2)}-${input.slice(2)}`;
  else if (inputLength === 2 && input[2] === '-') input = input.slice(0,2);
  return input
}

The problem with the above code is that if I have 'AB-' and I delete with backspace, it won't delete. I have to add a number like 'AB-2' and then it will delete leaving me with 'AB'. How can the above be improved? Is there an easier way to do it in regex?
I tried using regex as follows but have not been succefull:
const transformInput = (input) => {
  return input.replace(/(\d[A-Z0-9]{2})(\d{1-9})/, '$1-$2')
}

Thanks

The easier solution might be to not programmatically add/remove characters from an input field but to alert the user if what they've entered doesn't match the right pattern.

if (inputLength > 2 &&  input[2] !== '-')

I think I've never seen an input field like this implemented flawlessly (e.g.: cut & paste operations...). It's just too difficult. It's much easier to check the validity, as Andy said.

Here's a solution using regex, it allows you to type only valid pattern:


document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(
    /^([a-z0-9]{1,2})((?<=..)-)?(\d{1,9})?.*|.+/i, 
    (_, $1 = '', $2 = '', $3 = '') => ($2 || $3 ? `${$1}-${$3}` : $1).toUpperCase()
  );
});
<input>



The substitution pattern is a little bit more complex than the pattern for validation (/^[0-9A-Z]{2}-\d{9}$/).

regex

^                 # beggining of the input
([a-z0-9]{1,2})   # 1 or 2 alphanumerics, put in group $1
((?<=..)-)?       # an optional hyphen, but only register it when it is preceded by at least two characters, group $2
(\d{1,9})?        # 1 to 9 digits, optional, group $3
.*                # anything after this pattern that needs the be discarded
|                 # if the previous pattern doesn't match
.+                # then discard everything


substitution function

// if the hyphen ($2) or following digits ($3) is captured, transform it into `AA-0123456789` format
// otherwise only keep the first part
(_, $1 = '', $2 = '', $3 = '') => ($2 || $3 ? `${$1}-${$3}` : $1).toUpperCase()


This seems to cover most cases
Have to save the last keystroke if you want to magically remove the - when appropriate
It could do with a little more work to handle where the caret is so it doesn't keep jumping to the end


let lastKey = null;
const transformInput = (input) => {
  const inputLength = input.length;
  const nodash = input.replaceAll('-', '');
  const hasDash = input.includes('-');
  if (inputLength < 3 && lastKey === 'Backspace') {
    return nodash.slice(0,2);
  }
  if (inputLength > 2) {
    if (nodash.length > 2) {
      return `${nodash.slice(0,2)}-${nodash.slice(2)}`;
    }
    return nodash;
  }
  return input
}
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  input.value = transformInput(input.value);
})
input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  lastKey = e.key;
})
<input>



